# how can I retrieve the shorcut-key for the hardOps mirror function (alt + X)?

Tags: mirror, mirror-modifier, hard-ops

for those that are using Hardops: the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>–<kbd>X</kbd> is not working for me for the mirror function. Is there a way to reassign it to use it again?

There is no short key that is interfering with <kbd>Alt</kbd>–<kbd>X</kbd>; so I don't know why it's not working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit Preferences; Go to Add-Ons and find HardOps.  Open up its preferences section to Operators.  The Mirror Gizmo preference is there.  Edit it to whatever you want it to be.

[image: Hardop preferences open to operators]

Comment: much appreciation <3

Comment: You're welcome.  Add-ons are uneven about whether they have shortcuts you can change, but HardOps is one of the better ones.